# Chrome tabs.onActivated.addListener throws an "undefined" TypeError

Tags: google-chrome-extension, typeerror

I'm doing a chrome extension, and there is in the doc [this statement](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onActivated) about `chrome.tabs.onActivated`.

Whenever I try to place `chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener`, it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addListener' of undefined`.

The whole background.html :

```
<script>
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(info) {
    var tab = chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId, function(tab) {
        localStorage["current_url"] = tab.url;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The documentation is **incomplete**. As of Chrome 18, `chrome.tabs.onActiveChanged` is replaced with [`chrome.tabs.onActivated`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onActivated). In Chrome 17, the `onActivated` event **did not exist**.

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener( function(info) {
    var tabId    = info.tabId,
        windowId = info.windowId;
});
chrome.tabs.onActiveChanged.addListener( function(tabId, info) {
    tabId        = tabId;         // For comparison
    var windowId = info.windowId;
});
```

I obtained this function name by opening the console in the context of an extension, and inspecting the keys of  `chrome.tabs`.

Comment: PS. This was the command I used: `Object.keys(chrome.tabs).filter(function(name){return name.slice(0,2)=='on'});`, which returned: `["onCreated", "onUpdated", "onMoved", "onSelectionChanged", "onActiveChanged", "onHighlightChanged", "onDetached", "onAttached", "onRemoved"]` in Chrome 17.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is wrong with your code, it should work just fine.

Just make sure your manifest has the tabs permission:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
   },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(info) {
    var tab = chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId, function(tab) {
        localStorage["current_url"] = tab.url;
    });
});
```

Comment: Everything is okay, I have the permission... The thing that actually disturb me is that "undefined" thing.. Is the doc wrong ?

Comment: When you debug it, do you see the context correct? Add a breakpoint in inspector and refresh the background page to read the variables. What Chrome version are you running?

Comment: The Doc is right, I just ran the above code and it works as expected. in Chrome 18.0.1025.142

Comment: I think I just got why it doesn't work right... I have Chrome 17. I guess it's pretty new. Thanks for your help, I'll try after updating.

Comment: You are on an old browser :x and extremely vulnerable, yea update to version 18.