# Idea: Conditional Chrome theme based on environment

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, environment-variables, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-theme

As a web developer I'm constantly working on projects in different environments (local, staging, testing, production). I mostly work on Drupal projects. I can't tell you the number of times I've been led from local to production by just browsing the site. And then accidentally changing a setting on production that was really only supposed to be changed on my local environment.

So here's an idea: A Chrome theme that changes color depending on the sub domain of a site.

For example: on **local.mysite.com*** the browser chrome should be green, on **staging.mysite.com*** it should be blue, and on **mysite.com*** the color should be standard chrome grey.

This could avoid a lot of confusion for a lot of people working in different environments. Not only for developers, also for "content" people.

Sadly, I have no idea how to code a Chrome theme with that kind of behavior.

Comment: That's certainly a fantastic idea. I've often found myself making that same mistake! I'm fairly sure the Chrome theme format doesn't allow this sort of dynamic theming, though.

Comment: I saw something similar to this recently.  It used a greasemonkey script to overlay coloured info/warning boxes based on url of current page.  I can't find it again, but it shouldn't be too hard to put together.

Comment: Chrome themes make this super tricky, but I had a quick go: https://github.com/roc/colorchrome

Answer (score 9):

Themes are not dynamic, so the solution is not straightforward.

It's possible to create the feature using the [management API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/management.html). At least three extension are needed:

- The main extension for switching themes.
- Theme #1, theme #2 etc (an extra extension for every additional theme).

### How to

1. Create a theme - See [the Chrome themes documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/themes.html).
2. Bind a [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) event to listen for tab changes, and possibly save the state of known "theme-tabs" in a hash (by tabId). Don't forget to remove the tabId when the tab's URI is not "special" any more, using the `delete` operator.
3. Create another extension, with a [background script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html).
   Add a [`chrome.tabs.onActivated`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onActivated) <sup>**Warning: See below**</sup> event, to listen for tab changes. This event is passed a windowId and tabId. Use the hash, created in step 2, to check whether the theme has to be changed or not.
4. If the URL matches a certain pattern, activate the new theme using the [`chrome.management.setEnabled`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/management.html#method-setEnabled) method.

Alternative approach for step 3-4: Use [Content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) to [call](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) a method the background page. The [match patterns](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html) can then be set in the [manifest file](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#registration), at the `"content_scripts"`, `"matches"` section.

<sup>**Warning**</sup>: The **`onActivated`** event was [not supported prior Chrome 18](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9954420/938089?chrome-tabs-onactivated-addlistener-throws-an-undefined-typeerror). Before Chrome 18, the event was called **`onActiveChanged`**.

The extension as described in steps 2-4 requires the following [permissions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions):

- [management](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/management.html)
- [tabs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html)

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to use PHP to detect what server I am connected to and then update Administrative screens of my application (WordPress, Drupal etc.) with a specific color. You could also display a color bar at the top of local and staging sites as well.

Here is what I do for WordPress admin screens:

```
// determine if this is development, staging or production environment
if (strpos(home_url(),'http://localhost') !== false)   
{
    define('MY_ENVIRONMENT', 'DEV');
}
else if (strpos(home_url(),'<enter staging URL here>') !== false)
{
    define('MY_ENVIRONMENT', 'STAGE');
}
else
{
    define('MY_ENVIRONMENT', 'PROD');
}
```

And then I used this to show specific colors in WordPress admin screen:

```
function change_admin_color($result) {
  return (MY_ENVIRONMENT== 'PROD' ? 'sunrise' : (MY_ENVIRONMENT== 'STAGE' ? 'ocean' : 'fresh'));
}
add_filter('get_user_option_admin_color','change_admin_color');
```