# What is the difference between onSelectionChanged, onActiveChanged and onActivated?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, deprecated

1. [Documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onActivated) describes **onActivated** as:`chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(object activeInfo) {...});`

   > Fires when the active tab in a window changes. [...]
2. As a comment on his own answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954211/chrome-tabs-onactivated-addlistener-throws-an-undefined-typeerror), @RobW says:

   > The correct method is
   >   chrome.tabs.onActiveChanged, with the same signature as the
   >   non-existant chrome.tabs.onActivated.
3. Finally, [a sample extension](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/pageAction/set_icon/) uses **onSelectionChanged** seemingly for the same purpose:

   ```
   chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function(tabId) {
     lastTabId = tabId;
     chrome.pageAction.show(lastTabId);
   });
   ```

What's the difference between **onSelectionChanged** and **onActiveChanged**? Why is there no documentation for **onSelectionChanged**? What should *I* use to listen to tab changes?

Comment: Note: At the time of posting, I (and you) were using Chrome 17.  The `onActivated` event **does** exist in Chrome 18. If you want to target Chrome <17, use `onActiveChanged` (equivalent alias to `onSelectionChanged`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `onActivated` (Chrome 18+ only) to listen for tab changes. `onActiveChanged` and `onSelectionChanged` are deprecated events.

In the source code (see attachment), the purpose of these events, and their usage. I've updated [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9954420/938089?chrome-tabs-onactivated-addlistener-throws-an-undefined-typeerror) with a small demo, for clarification.

This is the relevant part of the [source code](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/browser/extensions/extension_browser_event_router.cc):

```c
void ExtensionBrowserEventRouter::ActiveTabChanged(
    TabContentsWrapper* old_contents,
    TabContentsWrapper* new_contents,
    int index,
    bool user_gesture) {
  ListValue args;
  int tab_id = ExtensionTabUtil::GetTabId(new_contents->web_contents());
  args.Append(Value::CreateIntegerValue(tab_id));

  DictionaryValue* object_args = new DictionaryValue();
  object_args->Set(tab_keys::kWindowIdKey, Value::CreateIntegerValue(
      ExtensionTabUtil::GetWindowIdOfTab(new_contents->web_contents())));
  args.Append(object_args);

  // The onActivated event replaced onActiveChanged and onSelectionChanged. The
  // deprecated events take two arguments: tabId, {windowId}.
  std::string old_json_args;
  base::JSONWriter::Write(&args, &old_json_args);

  // The onActivated event takes one argument: {windowId, tabId}.
  std::string new_json_args;
  args.Remove(0, NULL);
  object_args->Set(tab_keys::kTabIdKey, Value::CreateIntegerValue(tab_id));
  base::JSONWriter::Write(&args, &new_json_args);

  Profile* profile = new_contents->profile();
  DispatchEvent(profile, events::kOnTabSelectionChanged, old_json_args);
  DispatchEvent(profile, events::kOnTabActiveChanged, old_json_args);
  DispatchEvent(profile, events::kOnTabActivated, new_json_args);
}
```